# Using alias from COALESCE from SELECT in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c0f72eefd7e5cf5693b3504799a2369c)**

```
CREATE TABLE logistics (
    id int primary key,
    campaign VARCHAR(255),
    inbound_date VARCHAR(255),
    outbound_date VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO logistics
(id, campaign, inbound_date, outbound_date)
VALUES 
("1", "C001", "2019-01-01", "2019-02-08"),
("2", "C001", "2019-05-10", "2019-05-12"),
("3", "C001", "2019-06-12", "2019-06-15"),
("4", "C001", "2019-08-13", "2019-08-20"),
("5", "C001", "2019-11-14", "2019-11-22");
```

In the table above I have the columns `inbound_date` and `outbound_date` for date values. 
In my query I `coalesce` them to one column called `event_date`.

Now, I want to use the alias for the `coalesce` in the `WHERE` clause of my query but I get error `Unknown column 'event_date' in 'where clause'`:

```
SELECT
campaign,
coalesce(inbound_date, outbound_date) as event_date
FROM logistics
WHERE
event_date BETWEEN "2019-06-01" AND "2019-10-01"
```

I know I could solve the issue by using the `inbound_date` and `outbound_date` as two seperate conditions in the `WHERE` clause but isn't there a smarter way using the alias of the `coalesce`?

Comment: *In my query I coalesce them to one column called event_date.* All your data contains dates which are NOT NULL. So COALESCE() will return `inbound_date` for all records. Explain what do you want to obtain REALLY? Maybe some `inbound_date` values are NULL? if so edit sample data table...

Comment: You *could* use HAVING, but this is ill-advised. Best just to repeat the COALESCE

Comment: I think a smart way would be to use  a view with the event_date column, especially when this use of the dates is repeated at other places

Comment: @Akina. Thanks for the hint. I will open a another question for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat the expression or use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT campaign,
       coalesce(inbound_date, outbound_date) as event_date
FROM logistics
HAVING event_date BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-10-01';
```

I don't recommend a subquery in MySQL.  MySQL has a tendency to materialize subqueries (although this has improved with more recent versions).  That can impede optimization.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2fcb11365f6e04340409bc52c7c7618e

Answer (score 4):

I believe you could do this:

```
SELECT campaign, event_date
FROM (
  SELECT
  campaign,
  coalesce(inbound_date, outbound_date) as event_date
  FROM logistics
)
WHERE
event_date BETWEEN "2019-06-01" AND "2019-10-01"
```

(Not sure if this is something specific to MySQL, but in generic SQL I'd expect single quotes not double around those strings.)

Note that in any case, I think this is unlikely to utilize an index on either date column.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ce9ab2ce54bf7f737288ad467314916f

Answer (score 3):

Why not also use `coalesce` in your `WHERE` clause?

See below:

```
SELECT
campaign,
coalesce(inbound_date, outbound_date) as event_date
FROM logistics
WHERE
coalesce(inbound_date, outbound_date) BETWEEN "2019-06-01" AND "2019-10-01"
```

yields:

```
campaign event_date
C001    2019-06-12
C001    2019-08-13
```

[FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=bf9481b14b0ab32abc55388cec90165c)